# Does Git isolate branches when pushing changes?

Tags: git, push, git-branch

When I have a repository with the following settings:

- branch `dev` with fetch/push remote (A)
- branch `master` with fetch/push remote (B)

and I push branch `dev` to (A), will `git` send to the server **only** changes applied to this branch or is there a risk that other changes will get there too?

In other words: is `git` strict about branches when pushing changes to the server?

---

Background: remote (B) contains internal code modifications that I don't want to notify the other remote about.

Comment: Git pushes *commits*, not changes. Commits are snapshots, independent of each other. The set of commits that gets sent is under your control: you generally request that your Git send the tips of various branches, which drags with them all the commits leading *to* those tips. RomainValeri's answer is correct, with the caveat that you're pushing commits (whole chains of them), not changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When you do a `git push` without giving a specific branch to push**

It depends on the `push.default` setting entry in your config. ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault))

In short, a push would push all branches to their counterparts ONLY if `push.default` was set to `'matching'`, which is not the default value any more since Git 2.0.

---

**And when you specify the branch to push**

You're sure to push only it.

Comment: Also, if you're unsure about the result of a push but you **need** to be sure : use `--dry-run` for your push and see what *would* have happened without impacting anything.